# C# Deleting multiple buttons at once

Tags: c#

I'm using C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
I have a program where I create a set of buttons on the fly, all are assigned the same event handler. (Fancy way for the user to choose an option.)  Once this option is chosen I need to destroy all these buttons.  I have been using the following code:

```
 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
 {
     if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
     {
         c.Click -= new EventHandler(TeamChoiceButton_Click);
         this.Controls.Remove(c);
         c.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The problem is it is deleting every other button.  I'm assuming since I'm deleting them inside the foreach, its adjusting the index so its making it skip every other one.  What is the proper way to do this?  Any help would be appreciated, especially if I'm misunderstanding why its skipping every other button.

Comment: Put them in a panel and iterate over `panel.Controls`

Comment: Use `for` to index into the list and iterate from the last to the zeroth one.

Comment: When you say `every other button`, are you saying it is deleting buttons you don't want deleted or that it is only deleting half of the buttons?

Comment: Side note: I would expect this code to delete only first button and fail on next element because collection should invalidate iterator when list of elements changed...

Answer (score 4):

Add a value to the `Tag` property of the buttons in order to mark them for a later deletion.

```
var btn = new Button();
btn.Tag = new object();
btn.Text = "xy";
...
this.Control.Add(btn);
```

Then you can remove them with:

```
var myButtons = this.Controls
    .OfType<Button>()
    .Where(b => b.Tag != null)
    .ToList(); //Because you cannot modify the collection being iterated with for each.
foreach (Button b in myButtons) {
    b.Click -= new EventHandler(TeamChoiceButton_Click);
    this.Controls.Remove(b);
    b.Dispose();
}
```

LINQ-to-object queries are executed in a lazy way. This means that the query is evaluated as the foreach-loop is going on, if we don't add a `.ToList()` to the query. Deleting controls from the `Controls` collection while the `Controls` collection is enumerated would throw an exception. `.ToList()` forces a premature evaluation of the query, thus eliminating the problem.

Comment: I ended up using an iteration from the back of the list, but I'd like to explain the code above to see if I Understand it.   The myButtons var is a reference variable of this.Controls.    and the various .OfType and .Where  are Linq functions to manipulate lists.  The .ToList changes it from an whatever type Controls is (IEnumerable?) to an actual IList type.  Since I'm iterating through the reference variable its indexes won't change if I change the data variable this.Controls

Comment: `OfType<T>()` and `Where(…)` are filters that are applied to the enumeration of controls provided by the `Controls` property. Without `ToList()` the `myButtons` variable would just be a query doing nothing until the `foreach`-statement executes the query. With the `ToList()` call the query is executed immediately and `myButtons` is turned into a `List<Button>` storing the buttons independently of the `Controls` collection. `OfType<Button>()` filters buttons and converts the `IEnumerable<Control>` into an `IEnumerable<Button>`. The `Where()` call filters buttons having their `Tag` value set.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the list backwards and remove the items that way:

```
for (int i = this.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Control c = this.Controls[i];
    if (c.GetType() == typeof (Button))
    {
        c.Click -= new EventHandler(TeamChoiceButton_Click);
        this.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
        c.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked exactly as needed (also thanks to Andrew Morton for the same answer).

Answer (score 2):

you can put all the button you create on the fly into a `List<Button>` when you create it
then use :

```
foreach (Button b in myButtonList)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(b);
}
myButtonList.Clear();
```